# copying integer parameter into an array element

Tags: java, arrays, variables, parameters, integer

Write a method called fillIntArray that takes two parameters – an integer array and an integer. The method must copy the integer parameter into each element of the integer array. The method does not have a return value.

Below is my current code, the test method applies random array lengths and variables for the integer, but I'm struggling with the concept of inputting data into an array. I understand pulling info but unsure of how to write the code to input it.
Can someone please indicate effective ways of writing this code?

```
public class Q8 {
    void fillIntArray(int [] array, int x) {


        for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
            array[i] = +x;


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop should iterate from `0` to `array.length` instead of from `0` to the value of `x`.

Comment: adding on to Sotorios... there's no need for the `+x`, just `x`.

Answer (score 2):

That code demonstrates knowledge of how to insert data into an array. But a few hints:

1. Your loop should go from `0` to `array.length`, not `0` to `x`.
2. It's a good idea to use `x` in the assignment statement, not `+x`. This makes the code more clear, and prevents bozos like me from thinking it will make the code not work.

Comment: `+x` and `x` are synonymous here.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code. You should iterate over the whole array and put value `x` in each location.

```
 public class Q8 {
    void fillIntArray(int [] array, int x) {
       for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
          array[i] = x;
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fasted way:

```
void fillIntArray(int[] array, int val) {
    for (int i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++)
       array[i] = val;
}
```